# How to find volume of a depression in a bone

Tags: finite-volume

This is known as an articular pillar. It lies on the outer surface of the bone. We have 3D Slicer openCV, but we are unable to find it as its a little irregular in shape and also its 3D in nature. Kindly help in suggesting how we may find it.

OpenCV couldnt be used because its to calculate volume only of 2D structures. 3D Slicer was used to get this image from the image of whole body's CT Scan.

in this image, you can see that lower right image, the left space's volume is what we wanted. And it looks like a void/cavity/depression in the top image.

Hope the question is understandable

[image]

Comment: The question is not understandable

Comment: In your first paragraph, what is "it"? Separately, though, like @MaximUmansky already says, the question can not be answered. In essence, what you are asking is "How do I compute the volume of X?", but you never clearly define what "X" actually is. Draw a picture that illustrates what that X is, and how you define its volume, and we might be able to help you compute this volume. But you need to start with a concise definition.